# Lost ESXi Hardware, how to restore ESXi machine from raw files

Tags: vmware-esxi

I'm running ESXi 5.1.0 previously 5.0.1U or something.

I have a folder with all the files from a VM in it, how do I import this VM back into ESXi?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Copy the files to the new datastore using SCP/vSphere client/whatever. In the vSphere client, connect to the new server and browse to the files you just copied on the datastore. Right click on the .vmx and select `Add to Inventory`. It will ask if the files were moved or cloned. Select "moved".

See [here](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1006160) for further reading.